# Trying to make the buttons clickable and canvas to draw on top of background image

Tags: image, canvas, background, rotation

I have this jsfiddle script that I am having trouble to do the following:

1. Respond to button click.
2. To show the box drawn on the canvas

I know that I could make this work if I add "z-index: -1" to

```js
    var sss = `
    .container:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 200%;
      height: 200%;
      top: -50%;
      left: -50%;
      background: url("${url}") 50% 50% no-repeat;
       -webkit-transition: all 1s;
      -moz-transition: all 1s;
      -ms-transition: all 1s
      -o-transition: all 1s;
      transition: all 1s;
    }
    `;  
        $(`<style id="dynastyle" type='text/css'>${sss}</style>`).appendTo("head");
```

But I don't want to do that for a peculiar reason that is too complicated to explain here.

Does anyone know how to get this to work? To be honest, I have no idea why the button is not clickable. [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/hongyan99/fa43vhd1/605/)

Also, I need to be able to draw on top of the canvas. BTW, I don't want to draw the image in the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking it for a few hours, I finally got it working. Basically I needed to do the following:

1. enclosing the buttons in a div that has the position attribute and z-index'd (I used 1, I believe that the default value is 0, giving 1 to the buttons makes it bigger than the 0 for the background image).
2. place the canvas in a different div and use absolute position to overlay it on top of the div that has the background image and use z-index 1.

When all these two things are done, I can remove the z-index on the dynamic style for the background image. What has giving me a lot of trouble during this was that I keep forgetting to add the position attribute on the elements involved in the layering.